# When to use ANSI-C Quoting in shell?

Tags: bash, curl, character-encoding

I am writing a simple library that generates curl command for a given HTTP request. I want the generated curl command to be as legible for a user as possible but also properly encoded.

In other word, should I use ANSI-C quoting and generate

```
curl 'http://server' -d $'name=Administra\xe7\xe3o'
```

or

```
curl 'http://server' -d 'name=Administração'
```

?

Comment: If you are generating code that will copy-pasted on a multitude of setups by a wide range of people, definitely keep it ASCII and make sure cURL propagates the appropriate encoding. You don't want the result to vary based on people's local encoding or misconfigured terminals

Comment: @thatotherguy Good point. Thank you.